# Printing out more values from char array then it's suppose to do?

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct

I'm currently working on a program that is suppose to read information from a text-file. The text-file contains a song list and I have created a struct that should be able to hold each song in a song list in my program.

I have divided the program in different files and they look something like this.

main.c

```
#include "FuncDek.h"
#include <locale.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
int main()
{

//For swedish and check memory leak
_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
setlocale(LC_ALL, "swedish");

//Create with starting size of 5
Song *ptr = (Song *)malloc(sizeof(Song) * 4);

int menuChoice = 0;
int nrOfSongs = 0;

//Read from file
readFromFile(ptr, &nrOfSongs);
system("pause");

do
{
    system("cls");
    menuChoice = menu();

    switch (menuChoice)
    {
    case 1: 
        addSong(ptr, &nrOfSongs);
        break;
    case 2:
        showList(ptr, nrOfSongs);
        break;
    case 0:
        break;
    default:
        printf("\nFelaktigt val, försök igen\n");
        system("pause");
        break;
    }

} while (menuChoice != 0);

free(ptr);

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

FuncDek.h

```
#ifndef FUNCDEK
#define FUNCDEK

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char title[25];
    char artist[25];
    char year[4];

} Song;

int menu();
void addSong(Song *ptr, int *nrOfSongs);
void showList(Song *ptr, int nrOfSongs);
void readFromFile(Song *ptr, int *nrOfSongs);

#endif
```

and finally the FuncDek.c

```
#include "FuncDek.h"
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)


//Print all from list
void showList(Song *ptr, int nrOfSongs)
{
    system("cls");
    printf("Låtlista\n");
    printf("-------------------------------\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < nrOfSongs; i++)
    {       
        printf("Title: %s", ptr[i].title);
        printf("Artist: %s", ptr[i].artist);
        printf("År: %s \n\n", ptr[i].year);

    }
    system("pause");
}


//Read from file
void readFromFile(Song *ptr, int *nrOfSongs)
{
    FILE *fileOpen;

    fileOpen = fopen("song.txt", "r+");
    if (fileOpen == NULL)
    {
        printf("Something went wrong. Could't open file\n");
    }

    char line[100];
    int counter = 0;
    int nrOfSongsInList = 0;

    /*Read all information to line*/
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fileOpen) != NULL)
    {
        if (counter == 0)
        {
            nrOfSongsInList = line[0] - '0';
            counter++;
        }
        else if (counter % 2 == 1 && counter == 1)
        {
            strcpy(ptr[*nrOfSongs].title, line);
            counter++;
        }

        else if (counter % 2 == 0)
        {
            strcpy(ptr[*nrOfSongs].artist, line);
            counter++;
        }

        else if (counter % 3 == 0)
        {   
            strcpy(ptr[*nrOfSongs].year, line);
            counter = 1;
            *nrOfSongs += 1;
        }

    }

    fclose(fileOpen);
}
```

I can now read my text-file and store my songs in my stong struct and I have allocated memory for it. 
My problems occure when I'm trying to use the showList function. I can print out the ptr[i].artist and ptr[i].title correct, but for some reason when I print the ptr[i].year it show the year + the title of the next song in the list.

My text-file looks like this and each row is ended with a '\n'.

4
Mr Tambourine Man
Bob Dylan
1965
Dead Ringer for Love
Meat Loaf
1981
Euphoria
Loreen
2012
Love Me Now
John Legend
2016

I can't understand why it prints out more than the year. I noticed that if I make the year array in my struct the same size as the other 2, the problem goes away. But I want to understand.

When I debugg in VS it says that it's stored the right values in the year arr.
Anyone know what I might have missed?

Comment: Ah thanks didn't even think about that!